Azure File Share: Docker Compose in Azure App Service writes to File Share but seems not to read the files (SOLR)
I am running an app with Docker Compose in an Azure webapp. The app needs a configuration, this configuration is a folder system. I have done this to start the app with the configuration, I download a tar from the repo and untar it:
version: '3.8'

services:
  solr:
    container_name: solr-server
    hostname: solr-server
    image: solr
    command:
      - bash
      - '-c'
      - 'cd ../.. &&
        curl -u :${DEVOPS_PAT} -L -o /var/solr/configsets.tar "<repo-download-path>" && 
        tar -xf ./var/solr/configsets.tar -C ./var/solr/data &&
        solr-foreground'
    volumes:
      - solrconfig:/var/solr
    ports:
      - 8983:8983
volumes:
  solrconfig:
    driver: azure_files
    driver_opts:
      share_name: solr
      storage_account_name: <sa-name>
      storage_account_key: XXX

I also created a corresponding volume mount on the app service. And it did the Job. The folders and files were created in the file share and the config was applied.
But now I have decided to assume that the configuration exists in the FileShare. So I removed the command and executed the container again with the following definition:
version: '3.8'

services:
  solr:
    container_name: solr-server
    hostname: solr-server
    image: solr
    volumes:
      - solrconfig:/var/solr
    ports:
      - 8983:8983
volumes:
  solrconfig:
    driver: azure_files
    driver_opts:
      share_name: solr
      storage_account_name: <sa-name>
      storage_account_key: XXX

Same fileshare, same volume mount. But the config, that still exists in the file share is not applied. Im not sure if it could be a solr related issue, but i dont think so. (I have not much knowledge about solr) The app runs, withouth errors, but also without the config..
But anyway i post the logs:
2024-06-04T10:42:52.973569481Z: [INFO]  2024-06-04 10:42:52.933 INFO  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.a.s.c.CorePropertiesLocator Found 0 core definitions underneath /var/solr/data

what means it finds no configuration for the core entities, but they are in the mounted fileshare
2024-06-04T10:42:50.471217712Z: [INFO]  2024-06-04 10:42:50.449 WARN  (main) [c: s: r: x: t:] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Not all security plugins configured!  authentication=disabled authorization=disabled.  Solr is only as secure as you make it. Consider configuring authentication/authorization before exposing Solr to users internal or external.  See https://s.apache.org/solrsecurity for more info

same thing the security.json is not there, but in the fileshare.
Someone has an idea, what that could be?
